# Need to return the :name of an object, even if it was soft deleted (using paranoia)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, soft-delete, ruby-paranoia

I have `Users` in the system which can be soft_deleted using `paranoia (2.0.2)` and `TimeRecords` which keep track of how many `:hours` a `user` worked on a given assignment and what their total `:cost` was for the entire assignment (`:cost = :rate * :hours` to keep it simple).

These records persist so even if a `user`'s rate is changed in the future, you will still have an accurate snapshot of what they charged for a given task in the past. **Enter the soft deletes.** A `user` can be removed from the system using a soft delete (setting `deleted_at: Time.now`) but I need their name to still show up linked to the `:hours` and `:cost` they charged in the past. I have a solution that works but feels too hacky for me and I haven't been able to find a more elegant solution. I'd appreciate any suggestions/help people may have to do this the **right way** instead of the easy way.

Current solution:

```
class TimeRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  def name
    user_name || "#{User.with_deleted.find(user_id).name}" rescue 'n/a'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TimeRecord needs the name, regardless of whether the User still exists or not, then I would recommend storing the user_name on TimeRecord as well as on User instead of delegating it.

When the name changes on the User, I would update the relevant TimeRecords accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I was debating doing this before but ended up going the easier route. Now I know better!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to pretend that soft deleted records are deleted for real to keep referential integrity. Since you already said a `TimeRecord` keeps a "Snapshot" of the User at that time, the solution should be clear: add `name` to the fields you store in `TimeRecord` as a snapshot.

This is a perfect usecase for this kind of de-normalization even if the User is not allowed to change its name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David; this is what I'm going to do--I would award you the **answer** for this question but Arjan got there two minutes earlier with roughly the same answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include associated soft-deleted objects, you can simply unscope the association like this:

```
class TimeRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, -> { with_deleted } # associate soft-deleted user
  delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Hieu; unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on Rails 4.0.0 (or it could be that I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: That query does work, but when calling `#user_name` created by `#delegate`, it returns:
    TimeRecord Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `time_records`.* FROM `time_records` ORDER BY `time_records`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 62 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 
=> nil

Comment: How do you define `user_name`?

Comment: `#delegate` does that automatically since I used `prefix: true` (it will create `#user_name`, prefixing `user` in front of `name` because of the class it was delegated to). If `prefix: false`, then it would be called `name`.

Comment: how about if you try to change a litle in `TimeRecord` to `belongs_to :user, -> { unscope(where: :deleted_at) }`